Localhost displays only NGINX welcome page after running my app Angular application container Docker
Localhost displays only "NGINX welcome page" after running my app Angular application container.
Dockerfile :
"FROM node:18-alpine  As builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/application_immobilier/browser /usr/share/nginx/html/
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
EXPOSE 4200
"
do you have an idea please ?
run container with my app

What port are you browsing on localhost? How do you run the container? –

The port I am using:
http://localhost:4200
The command I use to run the container:
docker run -p 4200:80 applicationimmobilier:latest

Ok, I think you need to add into your nginx conf     location / {       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;     } . You could mount your config as volumen or COPY on dockerfile before CMD . Also, move 'EXPOSE'' before CMD command.  https://stackademic.com/blog/how-to-serve-an-angular-application-with-nginx

@Mate it's working , thank you :)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

try this:
# Stage 1: Build the Angular app
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build   # Build the Angular app in production mode

# Stage 2: Serve the Angular app with NGINX
FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

# Remove the default NGINX welcome page
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copy Angular build files to NGINX html directory
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/my-angular-app/browser /usr/share/nginx/html

# Set correct permissions for NGINX to serve files
RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 80

# Start NGINX server
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]



i tested :

